# Passing Listview string to another activity Using Android Intent

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-listview, onitemclick

I'm trying to pass a string from Listview using intent. but I cant do it correctly. can anybody help me to find error in this code. thank you

**First  Activity**

```
public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    ListView ListView1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
        ListView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ListView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity2.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sms)));
ListView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String value =(String) ListView1.getSelectedItem();


        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,MainActivity7.class);

a.putExtra("item",value);


        startActivity(a);

    }
}
```

Second Activity

```
public class MainActivity7 extends ActionBarActivity {
String value ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity7);

      TextView editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Intent a = getIntent();

      editText.setText(a.getStringExtra("item")  );
 }
}
```

Comment: What is happening currently when you run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onItemClick() method you can get the selected item by adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i); then add it to the intent.

Here "i" represents the position of the item in the list and "l" represents the id of the item.